# What is IRDAM Journal?

Tags: journals, writing

I was reading [Clinical Chemistry Guide to Scientific Writing Series](http://www.clinchem.org/search?tocsectionid=Clinical%20Chemistry%20Guide%20to%20Scientific%20Writing&sortspec=date&submit=Submit). One of the articles is titled: [“If an IRDAM Journal Is What You Choose, Then Sequential Results Are What You Use”](http://www.clinchem.org/content/56/8/1226.full).

I have encountered this term in this site also. Can anybody explain this term?

A [Google search](https://www.google.com.tr/search?q=IRDAM%20Journal&oq=IRDAM%20Journal&sugexp=chrome,mod=0&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) asks ”Did you mean: IRDA Journal”

In the article I linked, it is explained as "Introduction, Results, Discussion, and Methods".  I understand its meaning as this readily. What I would like to know following points.

- Which type of journal articles are suitable for this style?
- Which branches of academic endorse its usage?
- Are there any other such styles exists?
- Are there any other abbreviations exists?
- finally but not least, why should I follow this type of sequence?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you look at this [article](http://www.clinchem.org/content/56/8/1226.full), you can see that IRDAM is an acronym for Introduction, Results, Discussion, and Methods. IRDAM is a style/format of presenting results in publications.

Quote from the article:

> The IRDAM format requires a substantial change in how the Results
>   section is organized. Because the methods are listed at the end of the
>   paper, or online, the reader is not exposed to details of the
>   experimental protocols and methods before the results are presented.

See also,

> The format used by many high-impact basic research journals, such as
>   Nature, Proceedings of the National Academy of Sciences, Journal of
>   Clinical Investigation, and Journal of Cell Biology, is arranged so
>   that the Results section immediately follows the Introduction. The
>   Methods section is placed at the end, or it may even be published as a
>   supplemental data file.

Comment: I’ll just comment to say that I love this IRDAM format (but I didn't know of the acronym)… It makes papers so much more readable to the non-expert, while retaining all the information needed.